# Converting nvarchar data type to number in MS Access Passthrough query for subsequent calculations

Tags: ms-access, casting, type-conversion, expression, nvarchar

I'm working with a SQL passthrough to SQL Server query in a MS Access environment. I'm displaying the query results in an Access form and performing a display calculation to it in a text box.

The data type is `nvarchar` in SQL Server. In the passthrough query I trim spaces in the select statement. All other uses of the data support this remaining a text type. But I would like to subtract a value when displayed in one particular place.

The passthrough looks like this:

```
Select
  ,Trim([NumberStoreAsTextWithSpaces]) as NumberStoredAsTextNoSpaces
  ,[Other stuff]
  ,[Other stuff1]
  ,[Other stuff2]
  ,[Other stuff...]
From [dbo].[Table of Numbers of Stuff]
```

When I get to Access the control data source of the form is the passthrough query, and in the text box control the control data source is:

```
=[NumberStoredAsTextNoSpaces]-42.0
```

This results in `#Type!` as a result in the text box.

Attempting to `CDbl()` prior to the subtraction operation results in a zero or null value minus the 42.0 and simply shows as -42.0 in the text box.

I don't necessarily care if there is a bad data item somewhere in the query, the Select ... Trim jumps right over that.  And the Access form should only error at the cursor.

What am I missing?

Comment: It works for me. Try testing with Passthrough SQL set to:  SELECT TRIM('   100.1   ') AS NumberStoredAsTextNoSpaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a pt query, then you can cast it like this:

```
Select
,CAST(Trim([NumberStoreAsTextWithSpaces]) AS real) as NumberStoredAsTextNoSpaces
,[Other stuff]
,[Other stuff1]
,[Other stuff2]
,[Other stuff...]
From [dbo].[Table of Numbers of Stuff]
```

So, for cast:

```
 int (Access long)
 float (Access double)
 real  (Access single)
 money (Access currency)
```

Comment: Thanks Albert! Casting to real in the primary query did the trick.  I guess access can't deal with the nvarchar type in the UI.

Comment: You have to force the data type - even a non linked table would have this issue - string colum can't be used as number unless converted